# LINQ query string[] group by multiple anonymous columns

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, group-by

I have a delimited file I am reading into a string array (file has no headers) and then trying to parse with a LINQ query.

I want to group by multiple anonymous columns (using the array indexes) and then sum one of the fields.

For instance, say I have a file in the format:

> 1000200034,2015,ABC,1
>
> 1000200034,2015,DEF,2

I want to group by the first and second columns, disregard the third, and sum the fourth.

So that I return:

> 1000200034,2015,3

When I group by a single column, I can get the result to return the sum:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> query = from row in data
                    where row[0] == "1000200034"
                    group row by row[0] into g
                    select new string[]
                    {
                        g.Key,
                        g.Sum(a=>int.Parse(a.ElementAt(3))).ToString(),   
                    };
```

But if I try to add the other column, I no longer get the sum, I get both rows returned:

```
 IEnumerable<string[]> query = from row in data
                    where row[0] == "1000200034"
                    group row by new[]{row[0], row[1]} into g
                    select new string[]
                    {
                        g.Key[0],
                        g.Key[1],
                        g.Sum(a=>int.Parse(a.ElementAt(3))).ToString(),   
                    };
```

I'm pretty new to LINQ and C#, but my SQL background is solid. Just having a hard time converting what I know. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to grouping by `new []` it should be simply `new`, also you have to specify field names for your anonymous types used in group, like:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> query = from row in data
                              where row[0] == "1000200034"
                              group row by new { FirstKey = row[0], SecondKey = row[1] } into g
                              select new string[]
        {
            g.Key.FirstKey,
            g.Key.SecondKey,
            g.Sum(a=>int.Parse(a.ElementAt(3))).ToString(),   
        };
```

With the method syntax it should look like:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> query2 = data.Where(row => row[0] == "1000200034")
    .GroupBy(row => new { FirstKey = row[0], SecondKey = row[1] })
    .Select(grp => new string[]
    {
        grp.Key.FirstKey,
        grp.Key.SecondKey,
        grp.Sum(a => int.Parse(a.ElementAt(3))).ToString(),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of needing to provide field names for the anonymous types.